# Querying StorageMap by Id

Tags: substrate-node-template, substrate-front-end

Having storage like

```
#[pallet::storage]
#[pallet::getter(fn account_assets)]
pub type AccountAssets<T: Config> = StorageMap<
    _, Twox64Concat,
    T::AccountId, OwnedAssets<T>,
    ValueQuery
>;
```

How do I query entries by T::AccountId (u64) from substrate-frontend-template?

I've tried something like this (following code in https://polkadot.js.org/docs/api/start/api.query.subs)

```
await api.query.nftsModule.accountAssets**.entries("accout_id_here", assets** => { /* Logic goes here*/ });
```

But it gives error like:

```
Error: Iteration nftsModule.accountAssets needs arguments to be at least one less than the full arguments, found [my_argumnet_here]
```

Without passing first argument it works (but returns all entries (not filtered)).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right now, you are using the `entries` method which retrieves all entries contained in a storage map. [Here](https://polkadot.js.org/docs/api/start/api.query.other#map-keys--entries) are the docs for it. In general, this should only be used if you need to access *all* the data contained in a map.

However, it would be better for your use case to get a single entry from the map, which is described [here](https://polkadot.js.org/docs/api/start/api.query). The code to retrieve the data (`OwnedAssets`) for a given account ID would look like

```js
const ownedAssets = await api.query.nftsModule.AccountAssets(accountId);
```

and would assign `ownedAssets` to the corresponding value in the storage, and you can then apply the desired logic to it.

Also note the docs [here](https://polkadot.js.org/docs/api/start/api.query#parameters--return-values) on how the parameters are treated by the API.